# The PDF name is considered as a part of the filepath

Tags: asp.net, pdf, web-config, filepath

I am generating a PDF and saving to the hard drive. I have given a default file path. The PDF I save needs to be saved in the following format : BSc/IT/C/ . The problem I have is, when I try to save the PDF to the hard drive, the name of the PDF file is considered as part of the file path as I'm using '/' symbol. But I need to save the file in that exact format.

Here's my code :

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Filepath + "//" + id + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

In the code, `Filepath` contains "C:\Users\acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject" which I have defined in the "web.config" file. The `id` contains "BSc/IT/C/". Is there any way in which I can save the PDF file in the format I need it to be?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create file name containing /

**Because**

The following reserved characters:

```
 < (less than) 
 > (greater than)
 : (colon) 
 " (double quote) 
 / (forward slash) 
 \ (backslash) 
 | (vertical bar or pipe) 
 ? (question mark)
 * (asterisk)
```

Refer below link for more information naming conventions 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx